# TinyMCE is adding new line ("\n") regardless of apply_source_formatting

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE is adding `\n` as well as paragraph tags to my text. Regardless of the `apply_source_formatting` settings value.

ie.

Source Text:

```
<blockquote><div class="cite">Person said:</div><div class="message"><p>ffgfgf</p></div></blockquote>
```

What TinyMCE Re-formats it to:

```
<blockquote>\n<div class=\"cite\">Person said:</div>\n<div class=\"message\">\n<p>ffgfgf</p>\n</div>\n</blockquote>\n<p id=\"mce_1\">&nbsp;</p>
```

How can I get TimyMCE to stop adding new line characters like this? It really messes with the formatting on the other end when the text is submitted.

Comment: I currently have the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I don't believe so. I eventually dropped my project. I'll need to go back and see if I ever found a solution or hack for ir.

Answer (score 18):

Investigating the source code of *TinyMce* I've found, that in the [`Writer.js`](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/4.2.5/js/tinymce/classes/html/Writer.js#L58-L64) (now [`Writer.ts`](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/4.7.13/src/core/main/ts/api/html/Writer.ts#L53-L59)) class, the setting that is checked before inserting `\n` is called `indent`.

```
 /**
 * Writes the a end element such as </p>.
 *
 * @method end
 * @param {String} name Name of the element.
 */
end: function(name) {
    var value;

    html.push('</', name, '>');

    if (indent && indentAfter[name] && html.length > 0) {
        value = html[html.length - 1];

        if (value.length > 0 && value !== '\n') {
            html.push('\n');
        }
    }
},
```

So adding `indent: false` to the settings object seems to fix it.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  indent: false,
});
```

I'd still classify this as a rather *hackish* fix as the `indent`-setting is not [documented](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/) anywhere.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: This option is still not documented, but definitely helped me, too. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, we've decided to document this in an upcoming release.